# What's wrong with my code? C# Block Cheat-Engine and Other Hack Tools

Tags: c#, detection

I have written code in C # to detect all programs starting with cheat with a method like in the code block below. But even if I start programs like cheatengine when I run my project, the code I write doesn't detect it :( What could be the problem?

Save New Duplicate & Edit Just Text

```
static void Hello(string[] args)
    {

        //Konsol ac         
        Console.WriteLine("Anti Hile");
        for (; ;)
        {
            Console.Write("*");

            foreach (Process clsProcess in Process.GetProcesses())
            {

                if (clsProcess.ProcessName.ToLower().Contains("cheat"))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("HILE BULUNDU.");
                    Process[] Fivem = Process.GetProcessesByName("Fivem");
                    foreach (Process hope in Fivem)
                    hope.Kill();
                    clsProcess.Kill();
                    break;
                }

                if (clsProcess.ProcessName.ToLower().Contains("cheatengine"))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("HILE BULUNDU.");
                    Process[] Fivem = Process.GetProcessesByName("Fivem");
                    foreach (Process hope in Fivem)
                    hope.Kill();
                    clsProcess.Kill();
                    break;
                }

                if (clsProcess.ProcessName.ToLower().Contains("inject"))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("HILE BULUNDU.");
                    Process[] Fivem = Process.GetProcessesByName("Fivem");
                    foreach (Process hope in Fivem)
                        hope.Kill();
                    clsProcess.Kill();
                    break;
                }
                //icinde injector gecen butun uygulamaları bul.
                if (clsProcess.ProcessName.ToLower().Contains("injector"))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("HILE BULUNDU.");
                    Process[] Fivem = Process.GetProcessesByName("Fivem");
                    foreach (Process hope in Fivem)
                        hope.Kill();
                    clsProcess.Kill();
                    break;
                }

                //icinde lynx gecen butun uygulamaları bul.
                if (clsProcess.ProcessName.ToLower().Contains("lynx"))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("HILE BULUNDU.");
                    Process[] Fivem = Process.GetProcessesByName("Fivem");
                    foreach (Process hope in Fivem)
                        hope.Kill();
                    clsProcess.Kill();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: try to rename your method name to 'Main'

Comment: Once you've treated any processes whose name contains `cheat`, you have already treated all processes whose name contains `cheatengine` already, because `cheat` is a substring of `cheatengine`. Same for `inject` and `injector`.

Comment: Your second and 4th `if()` statements are redundant.

Comment: At the beginning of the code block, I asked him to write "Anti Cheat" before the loop started, but when I started my project, there was no message in the console

Answer (score 0):

I dont know cheat engine but I understand your code. You can use this

```
string[] valueList = new string[] { "inject", "cheatengine", "cheatengine", "cheat" };
static void Hello(string[] args)
{
    string mystring = "Test data";
    if (IsMatch(mystring))
    {
        FindHack();
    }
}

public bool IsMatch(string data)
{
    foreach (var item in valueList)
    {
        if (data.ToLower().Contains(item))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

private void FindHack()
{
    Console.WriteLine("HILE BULUNDU.");
    Process[] Fivem = Process.GetProcessesByName("Fivem");
    foreach (Process hope in Fivem)
        hope.Kill();
    clsProcess.Kill();
}
```